# jquery prop() immediately (on focus?)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to disable an element (form field) with the jQuery `prop()` method. There are two fields, one called `fee` and one called `currency`. Whenever `fee` is set at 0, the second field `currency` will disable. This does the trick:

```
        $("#fee").change(function() {
            var disabled = (this.value == "0");
            console.log(disabled);
            $("#currency").prop("disabled", disabled);
        }).change(); //to trigger on load
```

What I would like to achieve is that the second field immediately changes to disabled, before leaving the first field (so on `focus` instead of on `blur`?). The reason I would like to achieve this is that whenever a user uses the TAB-button he/she immediately selects the field following `currency`, in case the fee is 0.

Here is an example of what I have so far:
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/61wL928r)

Comment: You can use `keyup` event instead of `change`..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try on **[`input` event](https://javascript.info/events-change-input#event-input)**. it's immediate for any click or key actions. It boils down to `#fee` is '0' at that instant, `#currency` will be `disabled`. Try tabing, typing, or the spinner on `#fee` it works perfectly because `input` event doesn't have a condition as to ***how*** it got data, its only concern is that it ***has*** data.

Also, when you have 2 conditions and there is another pair of conditions dependent upon it, you should start with the default condition. I started `#fee` value at '0' and `#currency` `disabled`. Now that it starts initially at a default, that extra `.change()` at the end of the chain is no longer needed (although I'm not sure if it is useful at all...IDK I didn't test it).

Also added **[`tab-index='0'`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex)** to each input to insure tabbing continues onto the next available input. By default all inputs behave this way and a disabled element is never included in a flow so `tab-index='0'` might be overkill. Note the input proceeding the disabled `#currency` gets focused but it doesn't have `tab-index='0'`. Of course using `input` event would make focusing concerns a moot point.

### Demo

```js
$("#fee").on('input', function() {
  var activeFee = this.value !== '0' ? false : true;
  $('#currency').prop('disabled', activeFee);
});
```

```html
<input id='fee' type='number' tab-index='0' value='0'>

<input id='currency' tab-index='0' disabled>

<input id='tariff' type='number'>

<input id='tax' type='number' tab-index='0'>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use keyup function

```
  $("#fee").keyup(function() {
        var disabled = (this.value == "0");
        console.log(disabled);
        $("#currency").prop("disabled", disabled);
    }).change(); //to trigger on load
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#fee").keyup(function() {
            var disabled = (this.value == "0");
            console.log(disabled);
            $("#currency").prop("disabled", disabled);
        }).keyup(); //to trigger on load
```

wrong event :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `change`. Change doesn't trigger until you unfocus(blur) the input box. try this:

```
 $("#fee").keyup(function() {
            var disabled = (this.value == "0");
            console.log(disabled);
            $("#currency").prop("disabled", disabled);
        }).keyup(); //to trigger on load
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `keyup` or `keydown` events instead of the `change` to accomplish this, or if you want to use your existing code than just write it like this:

```
        $("#fee").change(function() {
            var disabled = (this.value == "0");
            console.log(disabled);
            $("#currency").prop("disabled", disabled);
            $("#somethingelse").focus(); //set focus to the field below currency 
        }).change(); //to trigger on load
```

This way when a users presses the TAB they will be moved to the field below currency

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```js
$("#fee").keyup(function() {
  var disabled = (this.value == "0");
  console.log(disabled);
  $("#currency").prop("disabled", disabled);
}).change(); //to trigger on load
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Fee: <input id="fee"><br> Currency: <input id="currency"><br> Something else:<input id="somethingelse">
```

I just changed the event from `change` to `keyup`.